# Ruby round numbers and paypal tax calculation

Tags: ruby, paypal, floating-point, decimal, currency

I've issues rounding numbers while calculating tax.

for example for amount `2.12` and a tax of `20%`, I calculate it like follows:

```
# this is on Numeric class
def ceil_money
    (self * 100).ceil / 100.0
end

...
amount = "2.12"
((Float(amount.to_f) * Float("20.0"))/100).ceil_money
```

result is `0.43`.

To paypal I have to send both tax rate and tax amount, and seems like he ignore my tax amount and calculate tax value based on tax rate. But the issue I'm having is that on the payment confirmation message I receive tax_amount as `0.42` seems like they round that to down.

I want to know what is the right procedure to calculate tax, round up (ceil), round down (floor).

Any other suggestions on this topic?

Comment: Most likely it is simply just rounding, but you'd need to double check with PayPal. 20% of 2.12 is 0.424, which would be rounded to 0.42.

Comment: `Float(amount.to_f)` -  maybe multiply with 1.0 to make really really sure it's a Float :)

Comment: Please don't use `Float` for this:  you're trying to do a decimal round on a binary approximation to a decimal number.  That makes the rounding direction for boundary cases essentially unpredictable, and it sounds like you need a predictable solution.  Use a decimal fixed-point or floating-point type, or integer arithmetic, instead.

Comment: To offer another take on @MarkDickinson's remark, the rounding operations when tax is added to monetary amounts is specified in decimal.   You should follow the steps exactly. This requires care even if you do it with integer arithmetic. If you do it with decimal fixed-point, either the fixed-point system happens to match exactly the rules for tax computation, in which case it is simple, or it doesn't, in which case it requires care too. Nothing is ever impossible in programming but doing it with binary floating-point or with the wrong decimal fixed-point system require special skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Ruby's built-in BigDecimal to get more accurate rounding:

```
require 'big_decimal'

amount = BigDecimal.new('2.12')
tax_rate = 0.2

(amount * tax_rate).round(2).to_f #=> 0.42
```

In this case, however, I think it's your own rounding method that is causing the problem because:

```
amount = 2.12
tax_rate = 0.2

(amount * tax_rate).round(2) #=> 0.42
```